# Using page sections as route in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I'm working with a design that has a couple of sections on a single state, and I'd like to be able to link to each section individually.

Is there a way I could render a single template with no outlets at a base level, and then trigger a scroll when transitioning into any of the sub routes?

Additionally, is there a way I could prevent a transition from altering the browsers history, so I could transition around states as the user scrolls without forcing them to hit back several times to escape the page?

Answer (score 0):

The main `application` template must have an `outlet`. Else you won't be able to render anything unless you want to do manual rendering with `{{render}}`. You could put some logic in the template to use with `{{render}}` but it seems overkill to avoid the convenience of `{{outlet}}`

You can model your state as a sub state with routes like, `post`, `post/new`, `post/delete` which correspond to routes nested in a `post` resource.

But, I don't think you can selectively use a route and not affect the url. You can only set the location to `none` to turn off location changes completely.

I'd just make sure the UI has a contextual back button that takes the user back to the previous state, skipping over states as necessary. So users don't have to rely on the browser's back button too much.

Comment: Not affecting the url isn't as important honestly - I'm more interested in being able to link directly to specific sections of the page